# How to set value of checkbox in magento custom module

Tags: magento

How do I set the value of a checkbox in a magento custom module? Also, how do I set the name of the checkbox to the value in an array?

Here is the code I use to put the checkbox in a magento module:

```
$fieldset->addField($entity_id['colorcode'], 'checkbox', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('selectcolorforimage')->__($entity_id['colorcode']),
      'name'      =>'assign_color_new[]',
      'values'    =>$entity_id['colorcode']

  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`values` (ending with '**s**') is for a select field: try value (singular)</strike>
sorry about that, try this instead:
Assuming `$entity` is the object you're working with, after the `$fieldset` declaration:

```
$entity->setData('assign_color_new[]', $entity_id['colorcode']);
```

Check out **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account** (line 142) to see how the core do it.

Comment: oops, new suggestion available :)

Comment: what is the object your applying this method onto?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
$this->addColumn('myname', array(
                                 'type' => 'checkbox',
                                 'name'=> 'myname',
                                 'values' => $this->_getid(),
                                 'align'   => 'center',
                                 'index' => 'entity_id'
                 ));
```

Replace myname with your required field name. Also `getid` is your code for dynamic values in this array.