# How to set value in checkbox

Tags: magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set value in checkbx in magento custom module.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814906/how-to-set-value-in-checkbx-in-magento-custom-module)

table is insertcolor. and     colorcode is field of insertcolor table.
so first get all data from insertcolor table. then add this data in to checkbox field . so id display but value not display. in id and value i put same value but not display in value field of checkbox.

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$readresult=$write->query("SELECT * FROM insertcolor" );
while ( $row = $readresult->fetch() ) 
{
    $categoryIds[]=$row;
}

foreach($categoryIds as $entity_id)
{
    $fieldset->addField($entity_id['colorcode'], 'checkbox', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('selectcolorforimage')->__($entity_id['colorcode']),
    'name'      =>'assign_color_new[]',
    'values'    =>'not set vaqlue',
  ));
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and provide some more background. This is unanswerable in its present state.

Comment: sir i added above comment for code. and plz give me code for that.and how to add checkbox in admin side.