# Magento, add and set a checkbox on grid and form backend

Tags: forms, magento, checkbox, magento-1.7, backend

I've a fully working backend page with a grid and a corresponding form to edit the changes on the corresponding model. I added a new field on the table, bit type, as it will answer to a yes/no configuration option from the user. I added the checkbox on both grid and form.

My problem is that after a couple of hours of searching and trying different approaches I can not set the checkbox `checked` value both on the grid and the form reading the corresponding field from the database. Also when I click on save on the form the value corresponding to the checkbox is always saved with **1**. Everything else on the grid and the form works as it should. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814906/how-to-set-value-of-checkbox-in-magento-custom-module), [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/20536/), [here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/using-checkboxes-in-magento-backend/), [here](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field) and some more sites and [SO questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmagento%5D%20checkbox&submit=search) but still no clue on what I'm doing wrong. Some solutions recommend using a combo box with `YES/NO` options, but I want a checkbox, can't be so difficult.

Grid code inside the function `_prepareColumns()`:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    ...
    $this->addColumn('banner_gral', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('General'),
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'banner_gral',
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'values'    => $this->getBannerGral()==1 ? 'true' : 'false',
     ));
    ...
}

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('bannersgrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('bannerid');
    $this->setDefaultDir('asc');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('banners/bannersadmin')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Form code to add the checkbox inside the function `_prepareForm()`:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $params = array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

    if (Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata())  {
        $data = Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata();
    }
    elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')) {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getdata(null);
    }
    else {
        $data = array();
    }

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', $params),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ));
    ...

    $fieldset->addField('banner_gral', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Is general'),
        'name'     => 'banner_gral',
        'class'    => 'banner_gral',
        'checked'  => $this->getBannerGral()==1 ? 'true' : 'false',
        'onclick'  => 'this.value == this.checked ? 1 : 0',
        'note'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('blablablabla'),
        'tabindex'  => 2
    ));
    ...
}
```

On the `saveAction()` of my form I have:

```
$campaign->setbanner_gral(!empty($data['banner_gral']));
```

Comment: Can you add your saveAction() code for the checkbox, you make need to do something like `$banner_gral = isset($formDate['banner_gral']) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Where I should add this code @R.S? On the form? As a new array element or outside the function? I'm new to magento, that is why I'm asking so mucho.

Comment: In your controller saveAction method

Comment: I had something similar,edited my question to post that code. Now will change it to use your snippet and test...2min after, not working, value is always zero.

Comment: Reread this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292772/magento-backend-capture-onclick-events-on-different-elements so that we dont run in the same issue like last time

Comment: Ahhh! there is a typo in your code, should be `formData`, it was weird for me, "what date is he talking about?". So, part of the problem solved, now I'm saving the correct value. But I'm not correctly displaying it either on the grid or the form. @R.S, maybe you should post your comment as an answer so I can upvote. Will try to check all the options before posting again, don't worry, but remember I'm still learning magento so somethings are not always clear to me and now always I know where/what to look/change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your controller saveAction() when saving the checkbox data do

```
$banner_gral = isset($your_form_Data['banner_gral']) ? 1 : 0;
```

**For Grid and Form Page**

In your controller you should have Mage::register(...)->getData() or Mage::register(...)

```
public function editAction()
     ....
     Mage::register('example_data', $model);
```

On your form _prepareForm()

```
$model = Mage::registry('example_data'); // NOTE registry('example_data'); NOT registry('example_data')->getData();

$fieldset->addField('entire_range', 'checkbox', array(
      ....
      'checked'    => $model->getBannerGral()==1 ? 'true' : 'false',
       ......
))
```

see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/20536/

On your grid _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('banner_gral', array(
    ....
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'index'    => 'banner_gral',
    'values'   => array(1,2),
    'field_name' => 'checkbox_name',
    ....
));
```

Comment: Great, now still the display of the correct value on grid and form still to go. According to this solution on the saveAction will check some more code where I didn't check before

Comment: See my second link on my question, is the same you pointed out. This solution always returns 1 so the checkbox is always checked. Just in case I tested again, I got this same result.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look tomorrow at first hour at the office

Comment: Checked...I already had on my code the `Mage::register/registry` snippet you posted, so still not working. I will update my question to add that code.

Comment: Looking through the new provided link I realized that I also checked this tutorial when I was creating my first admin modules with grids and edit forms. It's indeed helpful.

Comment: Your `_prepareForm()` snippet is ok, but the link provided uses an array. Same situation, just slightly different use of the data, one uses an array and the other the model approach.

Comment: This answer works except for me I had to remove the quote marks around the 'true' and 'false' so the line would be:
`'checked'    => $model->getBannerGral()==1 ? true : false`

Answer (score 0):

@R.S answered one issue, how to save the checkbox value on the corresponding model/database field. But the issue on how to correctly display the checkbox on both the grid and the form was not solved. After doing some more searches I finally got to these two links that helped me solve my problem.

To correct the grid issue: [Understanding the Grid Serializer Block](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/)

Now the part of code where the checkbox column is added, see that I added `array(1,2)` on the `values` element.

```
$this->addColumn('banner_gral', array(
        'header'   => Mage::helper('banners')->__('General'),
        'width'    => '20px',
        'type'     => 'checkbox',
        'align'    => 'center',
        'index'    => 'banner_gral',
        'values'   => array(1,2),
        'editable' => 'false',
));
```

Also if you take a look into the core code of Magento, the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Checkbox` returns an array of values. Taking a look here finally got me into the right path.

```
/**
 * Returns values of the column
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getValues()
{
    if (is_null($this->_values)) {
        $this->_values = $this->getColumn()->getData('values') ? $this->getColumn()->getData('values') : array();
    }
    return $this->_values;
}
```

To correct the form issue: [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Store_Edit_Form Class Reference](http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d31/class_mage___adminhtml___block___system___store___edit___form.html)

The issue on this case was that I was trying to use the `$this` but what I needed to use was the `$data` that is loaded at the beginning of the `_prepareForm` function. @R.S pointed the right direction, but it is not possible to use `$model->getBannerGral()` as the `$data` on the registry is an array, not a model. So, using `$data["banner_gral"]` I could get the needed value for the checkbox. Tested and it is working.

```
$fieldset->addField('banner_gral', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'    => Mage::helper('banners')->__('Is general'),
        'name'     => 'banner_gral',
        'checked'  => $data["banner_gral"],
        'onclick'  => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
        'note'     => Mage::helper('banners')->__('blablablabla'),
        'tabindex' => 2
));
```

Comment: Take a look at my code... your doing `$data = Mage::registry('banners_data')->getdata();` I'm doing `$data = Mage::registry('banners_data');` so that different between `$model->getBannerGral()` vs `$data["banner_gral"]`

Comment: Good point, will take a look right away and test. But nevertheless, the grid part was still not clear.

Comment: Have you ever thought about just editing my answer? The only way I can provide you with code that work a 100% is if i spend the time to recreate your code (which I dont get pay for). Why should I spend 2+ hrs helping you if you always just going to accept your answer in the end (this is not the first time). Also by create a second post by is base of my post only will confuse other users who are trying to accomplish this by having to read thru two post to find the answer.

Comment: About editing your answer, [this meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107509/should-i-edit-or-simply-comment-on-an-accepted-answer-i-consider-to-be-incomplet) question and answers may give you some light on why I don't edit your answer. In short: How to Edit
► fix grammatical or spelling errors
► **clarify meaning without changing it**
► correct minor mistakes
► add related resources or links
► always respect the original author